# Older version of Visual Studio Extension

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, testing, visual-studio-2012, chutzpah

Is there a way to get an older version of a visual studio 2012 extension? I want to get both

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f8741f04-bae4-4900-81c7-7c9bfb9ed1fe
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/71a4e9bd-f660-448f-bd92-f5a65d39b7f0

But I don't want version 3.0.1 because it's incompatible with my current solution. I want version 2.5.0. Is there a way to get the downgraded version? I cant seem to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get past versions of the VS extension [here](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/releases). But ideally the most recent version would work for you. What is the blocking issue?

Comment: weird stuff going on with typescript and definitely typed files, some tests weren't getting picked up when i ran everything through test explorer, etc etc. just decided going back to the older version where everything worked was more useful at this point than debugging every part of my applications test suite

Comment: I totally understand. When you find time please do file an issue on the Chutzpah codeplex page with a repro of your issue so I can investigate it.

Comment: A better place to get previous Chutzpah versions: https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/releases

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Just [go over to the codeplex page and look up the specific version you're after](http://chutzpah.codeplex.com/releases). Check the "Other Downloads" box on the right for earlier releases, [2.5.0 for example](http://chutzpah.codeplex.com/releases/view/111525).

Comment: I notice there isn't a 2.4.1 version on the CodePlex page. If you need this version, you can download it from the link in Matthew Manela's post.